# <element>.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '<reference>'); not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to change the svg code that I've used in my html page by changing the href of the 'use' tag using javascript. The code works fine in Chrome but doesn't do well in Firefox.

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT - My code

```
// javascript


function OnHover(x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
            case 1:
            document.getElementById("icon2svg").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#SVGicon-2-grad');
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("icon2svg").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#SVGicon-2');
            break;
        case 3:...
    }
}


<!-- HTML -->



<div id="vi2" class="vertical-inner-inactive">
    <svg> <use id="icon2svg" xlink:href="#SVGicon-2"></use></svg>
    <p id="icon2text">Text</p>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" id="SVGicon-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
    <path fill="#fff" d="M173.332,277.78v0.021c0,0-0.009-0.004-0.022-0.011c-0.014,0.007-0.022,0.011-0.022,0.011v-0.021
    c-2.244-1.036-97.775-45.949-89.042-180.789c0,0,39.924-3.001,89.042-27V69.97c0.007,0.003,0.015,0.007,0.022,0.011
    c0.008-0.004,0.014-0.008,0.022-0.011v0.021c49.117,23.999,89.041,27,89.041,27C271.107,231.831,175.577,276.744,173.332,277.78z
     M173.443,307.058c-2.9-1.313-123.891-58.404-111.484-229.797c2.538-0.191,50.776-3.814,113.438-34.318
    c62.256,30.503,110.439,34.127,112.975,34.318C298.166,248.653,176.305,305.744,173.443,307.058z M271.104,89.453
    c0,0-43.838-3.295-97.771-29.646v-0.024c-0.007,0.004-0.016,0.007-0.024,0.012c-0.008-0.004-0.017-0.008-0.024-0.012v0.024
    c-53.933,26.351-97.771,29.646-97.771,29.646c-9.59,148.058,95.307,197.376,97.771,198.514v0.022c0,0,0.009-0.006,0.024-0.011
    c0.015,0.005,0.024,0.011,0.024,0.011v-0.022C175.798,286.829,280.695,237.511,271.104,89.453z"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="SVGicon-2-grad" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
<path fill="url(#PINK-RED_topdown)" d="M173.332,277.78v0.021c0,0-0.009-0.004-0.022-0.011c-0.014,0.007-0.022,0.011-0.022,0.011v-0.021
    c-2.244-1.036-97.775-45.949-89.042-180.789c0,0,39.924-3.001,89.042-27V69.97c0.007,0.003,0.015,0.007,0.022,0.011
    c0.008-0.004,0.014-0.008,0.022-0.011v0.021c49.117,23.999,89.041,27,89.041,27C271.107,231.831,175.577,276.744,173.332,277.78z
     M173.443,307.058c-2.9-1.313-123.891-58.404-111.484-229.797c2.538-0.191,50.776-3.814,113.438-34.318
    c62.256,30.503,110.439,34.127,112.975,34.318C298.166,248.653,176.305,305.744,173.443,307.058z M271.104,89.453
    c0,0-43.838-3.295-97.771-29.646v-0.024c-0.007,0.004-0.016,0.007-0.024,0.012c-0.008-0.004-0.017-0.008-0.024-0.012v0.024
    c-53.933,26.351-97.771,29.646-97.771,29.646c-9.59,148.058,95.307,197.376,97.771,198.514v0.022c0,0,0.009-0.006,0.024-0.011
    c0.015,0.005,0.024,0.011,0.024,0.011v-0.022C175.798,286.829,280.695,237.511,271.104,89.453z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: actual javascript is better than your own made up pseudo code

Comment: Could you explain that code please. I'm not a pro in javascript.

Comment: There are plenty of regression and other tests in Firefox which have this working every time it's built. There's therefore either a bug in your code, or you have a different issue to the one you're describing but without seeing your code I can't tell what it is.

Comment: `Could you explain that code please. I'm not a pro in javascript` - that is not valid javascript, therefore i can't explain **your code**

Comment: @AshwinThomas please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson

I've posted the portion of my code I'm referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use href rather than xlink:href

```js
x = 1

function go()
{
  OnHover(x);
  x = 3-x;
  }

function OnHover(x)
{
      switch (x)
    {
            case 1:
            document.getElementById("icon2svg").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#SVGicon-2-grad');
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("icon2svg").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#SVGicon-2');
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="vi2" class="vertical-inner-inactive">
    <svg> <use onclick="go()" id="icon2svg" xlink:href="#SVGicon-2"></use></svg>
    <p id="icon2text">Text</p>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" id="SVGicon-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
    <path fill="black" d="M173.332,277.78v0.021c0,0-0.009-0.004-0.022-0.011c-0.014,0.007-0.022,0.011-0.022,0.011v-0.021
    c-2.244-1.036-97.775-45.949-89.042-180.789c0,0,39.924-3.001,89.042-27V69.97c0.007,0.003,0.015,0.007,0.022,0.011
    c0.008-0.004,0.014-0.008,0.022-0.011v0.021c49.117,23.999,89.041,27,89.041,27C271.107,231.831,175.577,276.744,173.332,277.78z
     M173.443,307.058c-2.9-1.313-123.891-58.404-111.484-229.797c2.538-0.191,50.776-3.814,113.438-34.318
    c62.256,30.503,110.439,34.127,112.975,34.318C298.166,248.653,176.305,305.744,173.443,307.058z M271.104,89.453
    c0,0-43.838-3.295-97.771-29.646v-0.024c-0.007,0.004-0.016,0.007-0.024,0.012c-0.008-0.004-0.017-0.008-0.024-0.012v0.024
    c-53.933,26.351-97.771,29.646-97.771,29.646c-9.59,148.058,95.307,197.376,97.771,198.514v0.022c0,0,0.009-0.006,0.024-0.011
    c0.015,0.005,0.024,0.011,0.024,0.011v-0.022C175.798,286.829,280.695,237.511,271.104,89.453z"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="SVGicon-2-grad" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
<path fill="red" d="M173.332,277.78v0.021c0,0-0.009-0.004-0.022-0.011c-0.014,0.007-0.022,0.011-0.022,0.011v-0.021
    c-2.244-1.036-97.775-45.949-89.042-180.789c0,0,39.924-3.001,89.042-27V69.97c0.007,0.003,0.015,0.007,0.022,0.011
    c0.008-0.004,0.014-0.008,0.022-0.011v0.021c49.117,23.999,89.041,27,89.041,27C271.107,231.831,175.577,276.744,173.332,277.78z
     M173.443,307.058c-2.9-1.313-123.891-58.404-111.484-229.797c2.538-0.191,50.776-3.814,113.438-34.318
    c62.256,30.503,110.439,34.127,112.975,34.318C298.166,248.653,176.305,305.744,173.443,307.058z M271.104,89.453
    c0,0-43.838-3.295-97.771-29.646v-0.024c-0.007,0.004-0.016,0.007-0.024,0.012c-0.008-0.004-0.017-0.008-0.024-0.012v0.024
    c-53.933,26.351-97.771,29.646-97.771,29.646c-9.59,148.058,95.307,197.376,97.771,198.514v0.022c0,0,0.009-0.006,0.024-0.011
    c0.015,0.005,0.024,0.011,0.024,0.011v-0.022C175.798,286.829,280.695,237.511,271.104,89.453z"/>
</svg>
```